# Tengo una tabla en HTML la cargo con datos de firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

Este es el codigo que html que coloca los datos en la tabla, el formato de fecha en el registro de firebase es DD/MM/YYYY, y quiero que me de el siguiente formato al mostrarlo en la tabla YYYY-MM-DD.
¿De que manera lo puedo hacer?[[image: 1]]
Saludos y gracias.

```
<table align="center" border="1" style="width:auto; height:20px;" id="tblReporte" class="display"  style="width:100%; padding-top: 10px;" >
  <thead>
    <th width="400 ">Fecha</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="value in DB">
      <td>{{value.fechax.toString("YYYY-MM-DD")}}</td>
```

Comment: estas usando angular que version para que uses un pipe

Comment: Esa usando javascript vanilla.

Comment: src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.0.4/firebase.js"></script>
<!-- AngularFire -->
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.9.2/angularfire.min.js"></script>

Comment: Si es angular..

Comment: ¿Estas usando angular?

Comment: Dame un momento y ahora te doy la solución.

Comment: Mr Kha, ya lo resolviste?

Comment: si ya se resolvio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No tengo conocimientos de Firebase pero para hacer una conversión de la fecha se deberá hacer con la siguiente función:

```js
function conversorFecha(fecha) {
    return fecha.split("/").reverse().join("-");
}
```

fecha se separa con split() y queda el array ["DD", "MM", "YYYY"], se le dará la vuelta con reverse() (["YYYY", "MM", "DD"]) y se unirá con "-" con el join() ("YYYY-MM-DD"). La fecha convertida se deberá visualizar en las etiquetas td.

Comment: Y como la integro al campo {{value.fechax}}?

Comment: Poniendo en cada td lo siguiente:
    <td><script>
        document.write(conversorFecha({{ value.fechax }}));
    </script></td>    Ya que supongo que los td los cargarás por un tipo de "foreach".

Comment: No me los muestra me muestra la tabla en gris sin datos.

Comment: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'nextSibling' of undefined

Comment: Intenta con:    <td><script> document.write(conversorFecha(toString({{ value.fechax }}))); </script></td>    seguramente convirtiendo a String te funcione, ya que yo lo he probado con String y lo ha pillado

Comment: Funciono listo, suaveee Kmevi10

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar el filter date de angularjs, suponiendo que fechax es un objeto date

```
<td>{{value.fechax | date : 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
```

[más info](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Comment: No lo formatea.

Comment: Lo deja igual, será por que en firebase todos los resultados son string o numeros?

Comment: Imprimelos en consola para saber como viene la data, si viene como string parsealos a numeros y ya los pasas por el pipe.